# DNS cache on Ubuntu

Tags: dns

Is it true that Ubuntu doesn't have DNS cache by default and what options I have to enable it ? Is bind9 option that can enable caching of DNS ?

Comment: Ubuntu has a DNS cache, yes.  You don't need to set up bind9 to set up an internal DNS cache on your computer

Comment: Where it is stored ?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Desktop have dnsmasq-base package built-in in NetworkManager, but with the dns cache function disabled, you can check in your logs:

```
zgrep dnsmasq /var/log/syslog* | grep disabled 
....
dnsmasq[1546]: started, version 2.68 cache disabled
....
```

you can install dnsmasq if you are using Ubuntu Server and this have cache enabled by default.

If you are in Ubuntu Desktop, you can enable cache in dnsmasq-base/network-manager with this:

add one file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/`

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/cache
```

add this line:

```
cache-size=1000
```

and after this in command line:

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

try to NOT install dnsmasq in Ubuntu Desktop, enable caching with dnsmasq-base. If you are in Ubuntu Server, install dnsmasq if is not already installed.

Comment: dns cache is disabled to reduce the **risk of dns poisoning attacks**, e.g. from others on free wifi network on other users on a multi-user host. See discussion at  [What happened to the talk about implementing per-user dns cache? : Ubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/2j0va4/what_happened_to_the_talk_about_implementing/)